# State updates with the old and the new values at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

I have been trying to update `initUsers` values on the DOM so the initial state values it works just fine but when I update `initUsers`  it renders different values from the expected ones.

So basically `entriesNum` get a number as an event and based on it changes the order of `initUsers` state value from something like this:

[enter image j here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hs5V7.png)

to this :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9cPV.png)

```
const [iteratedUsers, setIteratedUsers] = useState([...users]);
const [Newobj, setNewobj] = useState([]);
const [isNewObj, setIsNewObj] = useState(false);
const [initUsers, setUsers] = useState(users);`
```

```
const entriesNum = (event) => {
  const newi = Math.ceil(5 / event.target.value);

   for (let i = 0; i < newi; i++) {
    if (iteratedUsers.length >= event.target.value) {
      Newobj.push(
        iteratedUsers.splice(0, event.target.value).reduce((obj, key, i) => {
          obj[i] = key;
          return obj;
        }, {})
      );
    } else {
      Newobj.push(
        iteratedUsers.splice(0).reduce((obj, key, i) => {
          obj[i] = key;
          return obj;
        }, {})
      );
    }
  }
     
  setNewobj([]);
  setIsNewObj(true);
  setUsers(Newobj);
    
  setIteratedUsers(users);  
};
```

Because I have two forms of `initUsers` I hade to set two ways of destructuring like this:

```
{isNewObj ?
  initUsers.map((objUser ) => (
    < >
      {Object.keys(objUser).map((numo) => (
        <div
          key={numo}
          className="contacts-info  border-solid border-2 border-black table-row w-full "
        >
          <input type={"checkbox"} className={`${shortcut}`} />
          <div className={`${shortcut}`}>
            {objUser[numo].index}
          </div>
          <div className={`${shortcut}`}>
            {objUser[numo].email}
          </div>
          <div className={`${shortcut}`}>
            {objUser[numo].access}
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </ >
  )) :
  initUsers.map(({ index, handle, phone, email, access }) => (
    <div
      key={id}
      className="contacts-info  border-solid border-2 border-black table-row w-full "
    >
      <input type={"checkbox"} className={`${shortcut}`} />
      <div className={`${shortcut}`}>{index}</div>
      <div className={`${shortcut}`}>{handle}</div>
      <div className={`${shortcut}`}>{phone}</div>
      <div className={`${shortcut}`}>{email}</div>
      <div className={`${shortcut}`}>{access}</div>
    </div>
  ))
}
```

the second condition destructur the `initUsers` when it is not nested and shows the following result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiaLr.png)

And the first one destructure it in its nested form and shows the following result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9koK.png)

So instead of getting 5 rows the result of destructuring the nested initUsers I get 9.

Answer (score 0):

You cant update the state by this way Newobj.push that's doesn't work with ReactJs state.
You can use setNewobj(your new data)

And
setNewobj((prev) => [...prev,{}])
Here prev are the old data you have.

Answer (score 0):

react state is immutable, you can't modify it directly.

instead of `Newobj.push` use `setNewobj([...Newobj])` , your operation to modify Newobj

after setting Newobj you should first `setUsers(Newobj)` then `setNewobj([])`;